# jquery.ajax ping with head method

Tags: jquery, ajax, ping, head

I am working on a project which checks multiple websites whether they are online or not. I tried to make use of the following code to check a well known website, as a trial but all the time it returns error. How could I fix it?

```
function Ping() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "HEAD",
        url: "http://www.google.com",
        success: function(result){
            alert('reply');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('failure');
        }
    });
}
window.setInterval(Ping, 10000);
```

Comment: You're most likely going to be beaten by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Same-origin_policy), meaning your `success` handler will never be hit.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So how could I solve this out. I want to check whether any wesite is online or offline. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The workaround is to use a local server-side proxy to do this, and then query that via jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

The alternate to server-side proxy using javascript is to load image (new Image()) with the url you wish to ping and check the status in onload/onerror event of image.

e.g.:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
// the ip/domain is online
}

img.onerror = function(e){ 
// the ip/domain is online
}

img.src = 'http://www.google.co.in'; // the ip/domain to ping
```

Complete example is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/

It is not a complete solution, but need further implementation ;)